# Can I pass a NULL where int* is expected?

Tags: c, pointers, null, function-prototypes

I have a function with the following prototype `void init(int *argc,char**argv);` but in a subsequent call of this function in my program I don't need or even have need to provide such arguments.  So I make a variable called `int_null`(oh,bad name,I know) and pass to function `init(&int_null, NULL)` but come to my mind that `NULL` has-zero value by standard and I could use it instead of `int_null` variable(just for avoid create this variable), as the folloing `init(NULL,NULL)` it works fine. But can I have some problem? some implementations define `NULL` as `(void*)0` or `0`or `0L` and I'm sure if it can be a problem. The function needs to understand that `argc` is zero.

Comment: I believe if there `ptr` is a pointer of any kind almost you can always assign `prt=NULL` without typecast and no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char **bla1 = (void *) 0;
char **bla2 = 0;
char **bla3 = 0L;
```

All these assignments (initialization is done as per assigment) are valid in C and equivalent.

You can pass always `NULL` if the expected argument is of type `int *` or `char **`.

As [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) added in his comment, this last sentence is true but with the exceptions of functions that accept a variable number of arguments and functions defined in the prototyped (old-style) syntax. In both these cases a cast would be required.

Comment: Hi Ouah! ..please view my comment to this question & let me know if I am wrong. and good answered!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it is always true as long as `ptr` is a pointer to an object or a pointer to `void` (`ptr` cannot be a function pointer).

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` should work; both `0` and `(void *)0` can be assigned to any pointer type in C.